# A simple loop issue

Tags: python, loops

Being quite new in python, I still have some trouble with loops and I would like to request some help from you guys!

Here is the data :

```
a = [146,780,1567,2780,3600]
b = [0.2,0.5,0.7,1,1]
c = range(3601)
```

The idea of the code that I am trying to build would be :

- First value in 'c' = 1
- 1 is <= 146
- 1 is concatenated with 0.2 and stored in an excel sheet
- Second value in 'c' = 2
- 2 is <= 146
- 2 is concatenated with 0.2 and stored in the same excel sheet next to the other value
  ...
- 147 is > 146 but <= 780
- 147 is concatenated with 0.5 and stored in the same excel sheet
  ...

Basically : test every value in 'c', if the value is lower than what is in the first index of 'a' concatenate the value from 'c' with the value in 'b' that has the same index that the one from 'a'. If the value in 'c' is higher than the first index value of 'a', test the second index value in 'a', if it is lower than the tested value from 'c' append the value from 'c' with the value in 'b' that has the same index that the one from 'a'... ect

Thanks in advance for some ideas...

Tom

Comment: Much better (and more likely to be answered) if you try to write some code and then show how it goes wrong. SO is not a code-writing service ...

Comment: You would need the `xlwt` package to write to an Excel sheet. See here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt

Answer (score 0):

#### Performing the operation

Let us first take a look at the operation from a python point of view. We will create a list containing the values we want and afterwards save said list to an excel readable format.

In our approach we want to loop over all values of c, check whether they are less than or equal to the value of index `i` from list `a` and if so, save the value of `c` concatinated with the corresponding value of `b`.

To make our life easier we can combine values of `a` and `b` such that when we want the first value of `a` we also have the corresponding first value of `b`, the same goes for second, third, ... n-th value. To do this we apply the `zip()` function which pairs up all values of `a` and `b` based on their index.

Appending two numbers is easier when done with strings, hence we first typecast the numbers to a string using `str()`. Then we concatinate the two values using the string's concatination operator `+`. Finally we typecast the result into a float using `float()`.

Using this knowledge, we create the following code fragment:

```
a = [146,780,1567,2780,3600] 
b = [0.2,0.5,0.7,1,1]
c = range(3601)

output = []
for number in c:
    for a_value, b_value in zip(a, b):
        if number <= a_value:
            output.append(float(str(number) + str(b_value)))
            break
```

Here we loop over every number in `c` and for each number we loop over the list of pairs in `a` and `b`. If the number from `c` is smaller than the corresponding value of `a` we concatinate the number and the corresponding value of `b` and append it to the output.

#### Saving to an excel format

Now that we have the output in a list format, we should save it into a file such that it can be opened using Microsoft Excel. As Excel is able to open .csv files, we shall write it to in a .csv format. Luckily python has a csv module.

We can write to a file called `output.csv` like this:

```
import csv
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows([output])
```

Comment: That's actually almost what I needed I just whitely modified the code and have exactly what I was looking for :

Comment: import os

    os.chdir('/Users/Hello/Desktop')

    a = [146,780,1567,2780,3600]
    b = [0.2,0.5,0.7,1,1]
    c = range(3601)

    output = []
    for number in c:
        for a_value, b_value in zip(a, b):
             if number <= a_value:
                output.append([str(number), str(b_value)])
                break
        
    import csv
    with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows([output])